# Does the Gagliardo–Nirenberg interpolation inequality hold on compact closed manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, inequality, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

The Gagliardo–Nirenberg interpolation inequality on a bounded domain is of the form
$$|D^j u|_{L^p} \leq C_1|D^m u|_{L^r}^\alpha|u|_{L^q}^{1-\alpha} + C_2|u|_{L^s}$$
where are there restrictions on the constants above except for $s$ which can be arbitrary.

Does this inequality hold on a compact manifold without boundary?

Due to the presence of the final term I am inclined to say yes but I haven't found a reference.

Comment: I don't know of any reference but have you tried to work with a smooth partition of unity or does that cause problems?